# Value sometimes returns as optional string with SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I wonder why the SwiftyJSON sometimes returns a value as **"myString"** and some other time as **Optional("myString")**

For example:

```
func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){

                    let fbJson = JSON(result)
                    let fbId = fbJson["id"].string
                    print(fbId)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Here **fbId** will return: *Optional("myString")*

Next:

```
static func loginWithEmail(facebookId: String, email: String, username: String, response: (token: String?) -> ()) {
        let urlString = baseURL + ResourcePath.FbLogin.description

        let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "fb_id": facebookId,
            "level": 1,
            "email": email,
            "username": username
        ]
        Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters).responseJSON{ (responseData) -> Void in
            //print(responseData)
            let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            let token = json["api_token"].string
            response(token: token)
        }

    }
```

Here **token** will return *"myString"*

So how can one function return optional() when both functions use **".string"** and not **".string!"**?

Comment: How are you printing the `token` in the second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwiftyJSON has two kinds of "getters" for retrieving values: Optional and non-Optional.

`.string` is the *optional* getter for the String representation of a value, so you have to unwrap it before use

```
if let fbId = fbJson["id"].string {
    print(fbId)
}
```

otherwise the String itself will contain the term "Optional".

If you are *100% sure* that there will always be a value, you can use the equivalent of "force unwrap" by using the non-Optional getter and you don't need `if let` anymore:

```
let fbId = fbJson["id"].stringValue
```

But beware because this will crash if the value is nil, exactly as if you were force-unwrapping with `fbJson["id"].string!` (which you should never do).

Note that SwiftyJSON works the same for the other types: `.int` vs `.intValue`, `.array` vs `.arrayValue`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`!` is dangerous especially when you don't know if it is optional.Just do like this:

```
func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){

                    let fbJson = JSON(result)
                    if let fbId = fbJson["id"].string {
                        print(fbId)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

That is because you are doing this let **fbJson = JSON(result)**
instead of **let fbJson = JSON(result!)**