# NSNotificationCenter issue: Fatal error thrown

Tags: ios, authentication, if-statement, swift2, instance-variables

I am working on an authentication system. Currently I can pull the API data and authenticate the users. I used an NSNotificationCenter dictionary to store my values and I can print out the string message but my boolean value returns an optional. Also, I am not sure where I should remove my observer once I am done with it. How should I go about implementing it?

**Code receiving user input**

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var pwdField: UITextField!

@IBAction func loginBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let loginobj = Login(userName : self.usernameField.text!, passWord : self.pwdField.text!)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.handlingAuthentication(_:)), name:"errorPresent", object: nil)
    loginobj.getRequest()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func handlingAuthentication(notification: NSNotification) {

    let dict = notification.object as! NSDictionary
    let errorFound = dict["error"]
    let errorMessage = dict["message"]
    print(errorFound)

    if((errorFound?.string)! == true){
         //initialize Alert Controller
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication error", message: errorMessage?.string, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        //Initialize Actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default){
                (action) -> Void in
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }

        //Add Actions
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        //Present Alert Controller
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else
    {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

    }

}

}
```

**Code processing data handling for LoginViewController**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import RealmSwift

class Login {

init(userName: String, passWord: String) {
    Data.sharedInstance.userName = userName
    Data.sharedInstance.passWord = passWord
}

// call this method to login
func getRequest() {

    Alamofire.request(.POST, Data.todoEndpoint, parameters: ["username": Data.sharedInstance.userName!, "password": Data.sharedInstance.passWord!])
        .responseJSON { response in

            var errorFound = Bool()
            var errorMessage = String()

            if let result = response.result.value
            {
                let value = JSON(result)
                var outcome = String()

                //No username
                if value["password"] == nil && value["message"] == nil && value["name"] == nil
                {
                      errorFound = true
                      outcome = "No username: \(value)"
                      errorMessage = outcome
                }
                //No password
                else if value["username"] == nil && value["message"] == nil
                {
                    errorFound = true
                    outcome = "No password: \(value)"
                    errorMessage = outcome
                }
                //No password/ username
                else if value["username"] == nil && value["password"] == nil && value["message"] != nil
                {
                    outcome = "Incorrect cred: \(value)"
                    errorFound = true
                    errorMessage = outcome
                }
                //success
                else if value["username"] != nil && value["password"] == nil && value["message"] == nil
                {
                    errorFound = false
                    if let api_key = value["api_token"].string
                    {
                        print("The token is " + api_key)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("error parsing api token")
                    }
                    //pass data to Users class
                    _ = Users.init(Name: value["name"].string, Email: value["email"].string, Id: value["id"].int, ProfilePicture: value["profile_picture"].string, Username: value["username"].string)
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "errorPresent", object: nil)

                }
                else
                {
                    errorFound = true
                    outcome = "No password and username: \(value)"
                    errorMessage = outcome

                }

            }
            else
            {
                print("JSON data is nil.")
            }

                let errorDict = ["error": errorFound, "message": errorMessage]

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("errorPresent", object:errorDict)

    }

}


}
```

Comment: Networking is asynchronous.  You're checking the result of the network call before it has had a chance to finish running.

Comment: @dan what should I be doing to let the network call finish running first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why you are not receiving your desired boolean outcome:

- The way you handle data passed is wrong

In your handlingAuthentication method, you should be doing this instead:

```
func handlingAuthentication(notification: NSNotification) {

    let dict = notification.object as! NSDictionary

        if dict["error"]! as! Bool == true {

            let errorMessage = dict["message"] as! String

            //initialize Alert Controller
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)

            //Initialize Actions
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default){
                    (action) -> Void in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }

            //Add Actions
            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            //Present Alert Controller
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

         }

         else

         {

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

         }

}
```

Where `let errorMessage = dict["message"] as! String` and `dict["error"]! as! Bool == true` would remove the optionals from your output

- The way you handle JSON is incorrect. From what I can understand from your other posts, the data you are looking for are in the form of an array.

This is what you should have done to obtain the values for your password and username errors:

```
 errorMessage = value["password"][0].string!
 errorMessage = value["username"][0].string!
```

Answer (score 1):

As Dan indicates, the code after 'in' will run asynchronously once the network request completes. Within that code trigger an event (e.g. An NSNotification) that the rest of your code can use to know that it is complete.

Edit to answer altered question:
You are still posting your notification before setting your variables. Move that post to the end of the 'in' block.

Edit 2: Regarding the nil error, this I think is to do with your use of .string, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36351823/2466193)

Comment: Hi @Ali I've tried updating it as shown in my answer but it is still not working

Comment: @noobdev Hi. You are posting the notification before setting the globals. Set all the appropriate globals and then post the notification. Also register for the notification before calling getRequest - that is probably not the problem here but may cause issues later. Generally you need to get your head around multi threaded applications and how to communicate between the threads.

Comment: I've updated my code to follow your suggestion but it is still not working. Is there anything else I can try to fix it

Comment: @noobdev you should ask a new question, not change your original one. However, I will update my answer this time.

Comment: Ah I see, my bad I am still quite new to this. I'm getting an Optional(0) for my errorFound variable in LoginViewController. How do I get a boolean variable out of it

Comment: @noobdev As I say in my edited answer: you are still posting your notification before setting your variables. As soon as you post the notification your handler for the notification may execute (as it is another thread, exactly when in will execute is not known!). So make sure everything is set before posting. At the moment your optional errorMessage is still nil when you post and you are forcing it with ! (never a good idea) which is causing the crash.

Comment: I know but the strange thing is, I can receive the string output for the error message but the boolean output for errorFound is an optional although both are in the same dictionary

Comment: @noobdev I am not a JSON user much, but I think it may be to do with .string - see link added to my answer.